# Unwanted line - problem

Tags: tables

I have a problem with the file pdf. The line that I do not know where it came from. I wants to get rid of it but I do not know how to do it. In the file line unwanted have indicated in red.

[image]

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\textwidth 15.3cm
\textheight 22.2cm
\topmargin 0cm
\oddsidemargin 0.55cm
\evensidemargin 0cm
%\evensidemargin 0.55cm

\pagestyle{fancy}
\headwidth=15.3cm
\lhead{\footnotesize\nouppercase\leftmark} %\footnotesize\sl
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\newcommand{\pustastrona}{\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}\phantom{}\newpage}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\kat}[1]{
\hbox{\vtop{\vbox{%
\hrule\kern 1pt\hbox{%
$\scriptstyle #1$%
\kern 0.5pt}}\kern 0.5pt}%
\vrule\kern 1pt
}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{15mm}}|@{\hspace{3mm}}l}
\vspace{-31mm}  & \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\hspace{-35.5mm}\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{logoumcs}}\\
\multicolumn{2}{@{\hspace{20mm}}l}{\vspace{-4mm}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{\hspace{20mm}}l}{\Large UNIWERSYTET MARII CURIE-SKŁODOWSKIEJ} \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{\hspace{20mm}}l}{\vspace{-4mm}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{\hspace{20mm}}l}{\Large W LUBLINIE} \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{\hspace{20mm}}l}{\vspace{-4mm}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{\hspace{20mm}}l}{\Large Wydział Matematyki, Fizyki i Informatyki} \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{\hspace{20mm}}l}{\vspace{21mm}} \\
& Kierunek: trallaaa\\
& Specjalność:  \\
& \\
& ... \\
& nr albumu:  \\
& \\
& \\
& {\Large\textbf{tralalallaal }} \\
& {\Large\textbf{trallala.}} \\
& (trallaaa) \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could it be the vertical bar in your `tabular` specifier?

Comment: It looks like you tried to make a MWE. Still, you could/should strip out a lot of packages and definitions in the preamble that have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Pasted all because I do not know from where this error.

Comment: I'm guessing because a lot of things are missing (`\documentclass`, loaded packages, etc.; there may be some interactions I've not seen), but I believe @StevenB.Segletes' suggestion is correct.

Comment: still i don't undested how i must to do it  and it is document class \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}

Comment: Probably you are using a customised preamble, package or documentclass of your universty. In that code is an element which draws lines left so some items.

Comment: You are asking for the line with `\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{15mm}}|@{\hspace{3mm}}l}`.  Get rid of the `|`.

Comment: But this line is not to be where I have indicated, it must begin after the word "Kierunek" and go down and it goes. Just do not  where I paint red line. This vertical line should begin later. HELP ME

Comment: `\usepackage{geometry}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{15mm}}|@{\hspace{3mm}}l}

\multicolumn{2}{@{\hspace{20mm}}l}{\vspace{-4mm}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{\hspace{20mm}}l}{\Large UNIWERSYTET MARII CURIE-SKŁODOWSKIEJ} \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{\hspace{20mm}}l}{\vspace{-4mm}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{\hspace{20mm}}l}{\Large W LUBLINIE} \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{\hspace{20mm}}l}{\vspace{-4mm}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{\hspace{20mm}}l}{\Large Wydział Matematyki, Fizyki i Informatyki} \\
\multicolumn{2}{@{\hspace{20mm}}l}{\vspace{21mm}} \\
& Kierunek: trallaaa\\
& Specjalność:  \\
& \\
& ... \\
& nr albumu:  \\
& \\
& \\
& {\Large\textbf{tralalallaal }} \\
& {\Large\textbf{trallala.}} \\
& (trallaaa) \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The `|` character and the `\vspace{-31mm}  & \\` line were causing it; if you want that `\vspace` wrap it in a `\multicolumn` as such:

```
\multicolumn{2}{@\vspace{-31mm}\\
```

or similar.